# How to add constatnt in optimization function using lpsolveAPI

Tags: r, optimization

My objective function is like below

```
z=10x1+K1+5x2+k2+2x3+k3 & min(z)
where K1 to k3 are constant.
```

for variables I can write

```
library(lpSolveAPI)
lprec <- make.lp(5,6)
set.objfn(lprec, obj=c(10,5,2), indices=c(1,2,3))
```

But I'm not getting how to add K1 to K3. Can you please guide me?

Comment: Are `k1, k2, k3` always fixed and known? If so, `k1 <- 4`; `k2 <- 5`;
`set.objfn(lprec, obj=c(10,5,2,k1,k2), indices=c(1,2,3,1,1))`.

I'm guessing there is more to it though?

Comment: You can just remove them from the problem and add them to the objective after the solve yourself. I.e. replace `max K + c'x` by `max c'x` and add K to the final objective.